# Kernel Upgrade in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel

Can we upgrade ubuntu 16.04 with linux kernel 4.15 ?
If yes, will there be a downtime during this process and is restarting the system mandated ?
Also can I also know the reasons behind the restarting the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Kernel 4.15

It can be installed while running.

After the update a restart is required.

You have to restart in order to run the new kernel.